# validating if statments for user inputs

Tags: php, html, if-statement

if 2 of these are true both error links show up and messages on top of each other, if an input is 0 if statement that validates empty inputs also shows up
also if input is not numeric but the other input is numeric php still calculates but just gives back what ever number you gave it plus the error code on top how do i fix?

first statement is to validate if any values are 0 and if operation is division to give error

```
if ($first == 0)
{ if ($operation == "Division")
  print("<h1>ERROR</h1>
        <p class=\"message\">YOU CAN NOT DIVIDE BY ZERO</p>");
}


else if($second == 0)
{ if ($operation =="Division")
  print("<h1>ERROR</h1>
        <p class=\"message\"> YOU CAN NOT DIVIDE BY ZERO</P>");
}
```

this if statement is to validate that the input is numeric

```
if (!is_numeric($first) or !is_numeric($second))
{
print("<h1> Error one or more inputs are not numbers</h1>" . "<p class=\"backlink\"><a href=\"calculator.html\">Go Back</a></p>");


}
```

third if statement is to validate for positive numbers

```
else if($first < 0 or $second < 0)
{
 print("<h1> Error one of more of your numbers is a negative</h1>" . "<p class=\"backlink\"><a href=\"calculator.html\">Go Back</a></p>");

}
```

this if statement validates empty inputs

```
   if (empty($first) or empty($second))
  {
 print("<p class=\"message\"> One or more input field is empty </p>" . "<p class=\"backlink\"><a href=\"calculator.html\">Go Back</a></p>");

}else{
```

Comment: Could you explain what is the result you expect and the procedure you follow?

Comment: if any is true it will display an error message. if none are true to process $first $second and $operator

Answer (score 0):

@irvdtcc Look at the code, I understand that you need to check multiple conditions and show result only if all the conditions are true.

Criteria to be Checked 
1) $first and $second are numbers greater than 0
2) $first and $second input are not empty.

BEst way is to use flags for each of the criteria as below.

```
<?php
$fl_positive=0;
$fl_num=0;
$fl_empty=0;
$error_message="";

//check if number is empty -- empty is true of $first=0 or $first="". In either case //empty($first) will result in true.
if(empty($first) or empty($second)){
  $fl_empty=1;
  $error_emssage . = "First or Second number is empty or zero";
}
elsif($first<0) or ($second<0)) {
  $fl_positive=1;
  $error_message . = " First or Second number is Negative";
}

//Check all criteria in the same manner

if($fl_positive==1) or ($fl_num==0) or ($fl_empty=0)){
  echo $error_message;
}
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\calculator.php on line 17 is what I get when I replace it with my previous if statement  on my file line 17 is $error_message . = "first or second is negative";